# HTTPS vs HTTP requests from Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, flash-cs5

I am finding that if I load Flash from a HTTPS page (https://ssl.example.com/) and try to make a request within ActionScript 3 to http://app.example.com/ the request does not go through. Same goes for the opposite (accessing https from a http-loaded flash script).

The request is failing, the requested data (passed from a PHP script) is not loading.

Now at first I assumed the trouble was with cross-domain policy files, but I have fixed that issue (I think).

Is there any security policy in Flash (CS5 btw) on HTTP vs HTTPS requests based on where the script is loaded from?

Thanks!

Comment: The only policy I am aware of is the cross-domain policy. How exactly did you fix it? And do you think you have it fixed if the reqests are still failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, starting with Flash Player 7 `https://www.mydomain.com/` ≠ `http://www.mydomain.com/` and `http://www.mydomain.com/` ≠ `http://app.mydomain.com/` when working with `crossdomain.xml` policy files [[reference](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)].  So it is quite likely your issue relates to crossdomain configuration.

If you're going to be mixing protocols, you also need to add `secure=false` on the `<allow-access-from>` node that grants access to your SWF's domain.

You can find a helpful guide to `crossdomain.xml` files on [Senocular's website](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html).